# octave ode45 'events' error

Tags: matlab, octave

I am running code in Octave that uses the odepkg 0.8.4. The first .m file called 'poin2.m' is used for getting a Poincare plot. The ode45 command in this file calls the 'spp.m' function.

```
clc;clear;
OMEG=1.02;
trans=2000;
N=2000;
xfin=zeros(N+1,2);
options=odeset('RelTol',1e-9,'AbsTol',1e-9,'events','on');
 xin=0.2;
 xdin=-0.2;
for i=1:trans
    if rem(i,50)==0 
       disp(i);
   end
    [t,x,te,xe,ie]=ode45('spp',[0 2*pi/OMEG],[xin xdin],options);
    xin=x(end,1);
    xdin=x(end,2);
end
 xfin(1,1)=xin;
 xfin(1,2)=xdin;
disp('Steady state starts');
for i=1:N
   if rem(i,50)==0 
       disp(i);
   end
[t,x,te,xe,ie]=ode45('spp',[0 2*pi/OMEG],[xin xdin],options);

xin=x(end,1);
xdin=x(end,2);
xfin(i+1,1)=x(end,1);
xfin(i+1,2)=x(end,2);
end
```

The function 'spp.m' contains the piecewise linear ODE to be integrated along with the required 'events' function.

```
function [xdot,isterminal,dircn]=spp(t,x,flag)
omega=1.02;
alpha=-0.01;q0=0.01;zhi=0.07;epsilon1=0.7;epsilon2=0.005;%epsilon2=0;temp=1;
if nargin<3 || isempty(flag)
if x(1)>1
    fh=x(1)-(1-alpha);
elseif x(1)<-1
    fh=x(1)+(1-alpha);
else
  fh=alpha*x(1);
end
xdot=[x(2);-2*zhi*x(2)-(1+2*epsilon2*cos(omega*t))*fh+q0+(omega^2)*epsilon1*cos(omega*t);]; 
else
        switch flag
        case 'events'
        xdot=x(1)^2-1;
        isterminal=0;
        dircn=0;
        otherwise
        error('function not programmed');
        end;
end;
```

The code runs well in MATLAB but in Octave the following error shows up:

```
error: Unknown parameter name "events"
error: called from:
error:   C:\Software\Octave-3.6.4\share\octave\packages\odepkg-0.8.4\odepkg_stru
cture_check.m at line 308, column 11
error:   C:\Software\Octave-3.6.4\share\octave\packages\odepkg-0.8.4\odeset.m at
 line 104, column 10
error:   C:\Software\Octave-3.6.4\share\octave\packages\odepkg-0.8.4\poin2.m at
line 12, column 8
```

Line 12 in 'poin2.m' is actually Line 6 in the first code that is posted. I have searched a lot for this problem in 'events' but did not find a solution. Can someone help me out?

Comment: I think that you may be using an outdated method to specify your events function with `odeset` – [see here](http://cosy.informatik.uni-bremen.de/sites/default/files/odepkg.pdf) (PDF). What documentation are you using? Also, your equation is very [stiff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation) because of the piecewise element. Unless you're using the events functionality to carefully integrate to the states where the piecewise elements change, you should probably look for a stiff solver (Matlab may be a better/easier option for this than octave).

Comment: I was using code from [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=31Ox36xjrXoC&pg=PA36&dq=switch+flag+case+events+matlab&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BGXNVPOnDJXg8AW2qICICg&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=switch%20flag%20case%20events%20matlab&f=false). Anyways, changing the code to the style in the link you provided worked. Thanks a lot!